# Flutter add property for object

Tags: flutter, dart

My code works but I want to update this with objects. But I don't see how to add a property value to an object. It must be declared in the constructor ??

For exemple I have a user object with some property.
But in my code I need to classify users by those with the closest salary to a certain value.
For that I want to add an index key which I then use to organize them in order.
This key is just used to classify my users to have the order I want

This index key is not base defined in my object.

**My class user :**

```
class Users{
  List<User> user;

  Users({this.user});

  Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['user'] != null) {
      user= new List<User>();
      json['user'].forEach((v) {
        user.add(new User.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.user!= null) {
      data['user'] = this.user.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{${this.user}}';
  }
}

class User{
 
  String name;
  int gender;
  num salary;

  User(
      {this.name,
        this.gender,
        this.salary,
      });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name= json['name'];
    gender= json['gender'];
    salary= json['salary'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['gender'] = this.gender;
    data['salary'] = this.salary;
    return data;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ '
        '${this.name},'
        '${this.gender},'
        '${this.salary},'
        '}';
  }

  void add(String key, dynamic value) {
    // ... implementation
  }

}
```

Here an exemple of the function the classify my user and adding the index key in a functions.dart file

```
List<User> func_orderedItemByClosestSalary(List<User> filteredUsers)
{
  switch (filteredUsers.length)
  {
    case 1:
    // One result
      print('un seul resultat ...');
      filteredUsers[0].index = 0; // Not work for adding the index key
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `filteredUsers[0].index = 0;` doesn't work is because `index` isn't defined on `Users` object. Add `index` on `Users` to be able to update its value.

```dart
class User{
 
  int index;
  String name;
  int gender;
  num salary;
  
  ...

}
```